# Jquery Ajax. Sending post with values from inputs with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, tampermonkey

I wrote this code, and it's working because I can see the logs in console. I have a little problem because i can't send the values to my server via AJAX post.

```
    jQ(document).on("keyup", "form input", function () {
        var value = jQ(this).val();
        console.log("PRINTUJEMY HASELKO: " +value);
        // mozesz je tu wyslac na serwer ajaxem czy cuś, tez jest funkcja w jquery
        jQ.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "http://result.php",
            data    : data,
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);                
            }
        });
    })
    .keyup();
}
```

I can see this error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

My PHP file:

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["value"] ){
   $name = $_REQUEST['value'];
   echo "Welcome ". $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: `data:value` not `data:data`

Comment: A huge mistake :) I changed it but it`s does not working anyway.

Comment: Did you check the url ? As far as I know, `http://result.php` is not valid as there's no host in that :)

Comment: I wrote this because i want to hide my website.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for another response. I'll try it later. Well, all the time i do not know about php file. Have i must use $post method or $get to catch a value from my script?

Comment: Ymm. I tried your code on Firefox. It`s probably working but i have a security error. Because i can`t send value from inputs to http website. I tried also this code on Chrome. I have a error : Uncaught ReferenceError: GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined. Functios GM is for Firefox only, right ? Sorry for stupid question but i am new in programming world. Regards

Comment: No, tampermonkey uses the same functions and syntax as Greasemonkey. You can use (most) greasemonkey userscripts in tampermonkey and via versa. What you need is a // @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest in your script, in order to allow tampermonkey to use that function. http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php . For your other question $_REQUEST covers get and post variables, you are good, but should do if(isset($_REQUEST['value'])). Better would only be to use safe functions like filter_input('POST','value').

Comment: I updated my answer for the last time. I feel raped. Please use the Internet to find some tutorials on what you are doing and then ask specific questions when you are stuck, in the future. I am done explaining basics and programming your spyscript for no upvote or reputation at all. Good Luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE:

Since you are coding a tampermonkey script, you should not use jQuery ajax to request your external url, but GM_xmlhttpRequest( details ).

jQuery cannot overrule the same origin policy, meaning, you could only send ajax requests to the local filesystem with jQuery (what is somehow senseless).

However, GM_xmlhttpRequest has no same-origin boundaries. It is exactly made for this scenario.

Take a look at the documentation for deeper information: http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest

This is an example solution with GM_xmlhttpRequest AND example userscript header:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        my First USerscript
// @namespace   myNamespace
// @description queries some website
// @include     https://*
// @include     http://*
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @version     0.1
// ==/UserScript==

jQ(document).on("keyup", "form input", function () {
        var value = jQ(this).val();
        console.log("PRINTUJEMY HASELKO: " +value);
        // mozesz je tu wyslac na serwer ajaxem czy cuś, tez jest funkcja w jquery
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://result.php",
            data: "value="+value,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            onload: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                var json = $.parseJSON(response); 
            }
        });
});
```

Have Fun.

Comment: I used it correctly. I posted like that because i don't want to show my website.

Comment: Your script have a logic build but i have a problem again.
 "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"
EDIT: 
I used function :processData: false,
It`s working but now i have a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: In my working code, I also added processData: false and contentType: false , maybe you need contentType: false ...

Comment: I getting a CONNECTION_REFUSED anyway.

Comment: Connection refused means, the requested server is refusing the request. Is the script running on the same domain that your php script is located? When you are on http://localhost you can send an ajax request to http://localhost, but not to http://goggle.com, nor http://127.0.0.1, because they are other domains, even when they point to the same machine like 127.0.0.1 and localhost have the same destination, but are different domains.

Comment: Good practice is using relative paths to document root in jQuery ajax, like > url: "/result.php" instead of > url: "http://yourserver/result.php", for instance.

Comment: My script is in Chrome browser. I have to use url: "yourserver/result.php".

Comment: Your script is not loaded from anywhere? If you just open your html file in Chrome, your javascript will not work, except for you query the file system -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Im using Tampermonkey. My script is loaded here. Keep calm mate, my script is working because i can see value (in console) of inputs.

Comment: you should include in your question, that you are coding a Tampermonkey script. This is essential to understand your problem. I only have experience with Greasemonkey (what is basically the same, just for Firefox, not Chrome) and there you have to use function GM_xmlhttpRequest( details ) to request an external url. It won't work with jQuery due to the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` property should be:

```
data: { value : value },
```

The reference error occurred because your data is stored in `value` not `data`. You were also trying to send it as raw POST data (without any key), and since your server side is looking for the `value` key, you should pass an object as above.

Side note: you won't be able to `$.parseJSON()` on your current response data, because the string `Welcome x` isn't valid JSON, but you should see the alert before that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used your tip and @Irfan TahirKheli. I have another problem : net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and i can`t see any logs on my website.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQ.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://result.php",
  data: value,
  success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);                
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response. I have now this error  POST https:///result.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. I can`t see any logs on my website.

Comment: @KikiEngine, that really goes beyond the scope of your original question.  Make some attempt to diagnose, and then write a new question with new information.

Comment: look at your url .. http:// result.php .. what kind of url is this. i think you should remove the http part from the url ? @KiKiEngine

Comment: @Irfan TahirKheli I deleted rest of my URL addres. I don`t want to show my website.